# Fill null values in a dataframe column with different input values

Tags: python, dataframe

Below is my input dataframe.

```
   A   B   C   D
0   8   2   4   NaN
1   3   2   3   4.0
2   8   4   8   2.0
3   4   3   8   NaN
4   7   5   6   1.0
```

below is my expected output

```
   A   B   C   D
0   8   2   4   First
1   3   2   3   4.0
2   8   4   8   2.0
3   4   3   8   Second
4   7   5   6   1.0
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: What to you want to achieve? What have done so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take some time to read [How to ask good questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your own attempt and show it to us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code it will render your output. From next time please share what you tried first.

```
data=pd.read_csv('your_data.csv',skipinitialspace=True)

empty_points=data[data['D'].isnull()].index.tolist()
tofill=['First','Second']

count=0
for i in empty_points:
    data['D'][i]=tofill[count]
    count=count+1
```